# Why need npm --save-dev

Tags: node.js, npm

When installing packages in npm, why do we need to add `--save-dev` at the end?

Example:

```
npm install gulp-angular-templatecache --save-dev
```

From the documentation online (https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install), it says "package will appear in your `devDependencies`." What is that mean? Is that mean, if I don't put `--save-dev` it will install on different directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `package.json` file, it will automatically add the `gulp-angular-templatecache` module to the `devDependencies` object within the JSON after installing it locally in your application under `node_modules` like normal. The only difference is the fact that it edits the `package.json` file to remember that devDependency. It installs in the same location either way. So after running that, your `package.json` will look like this as of now:

```
{
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "gulp-angular-templatecache": "^1.5.0"
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: Also note that `--save` will add to `dependencies` instead, which is probably more often what you want.

Answer (score 19):

package.json has two places to store dependency information: the "dependencies" object and the "devDependencies" object.

When you install an app and run "npm install" it pulls down both the dependencies and the devDependencies. However, if you do "npm install --production" it pulls down ONLY the dependencies, NOT the devDependencies.

The idea is that devDependencies are for things like test runners and assertion libraries; stuff you need while developing, but not stuff you need when you've actually deployed the app to production.